# difference between minus and except in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

what is the difference between minus and except in teradata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are equivalent, the difference being that `except` is ANSI compliant.

Comment: Hi I am new in Teradata so couldn't understand what does ANSI compliant means...could you please brief me on this?

Comment: ANSI compliant means the syntax conforms to the ANSI standard for SQL. See [here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

Comment: It is advisable to leverage ANSI compliant SQL whenever possible. This avoids the potential for problem when Teradata specific features are deprecated as ANSI compliant replacements are introduced. (e.g. Window Aggregation vs OLAP functions such as MSUM())

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link for you:

[SQL MINUS or EXCEPT Operator](http://www.coderecipes.net/sql-minus-except-operator-tutorial.aspx)